# Joomla how to make an ajax call to an helper.php module

Tags: ajax, joomla, call, helper

I create a module, not a component, a module because it should appears a number of times, on a number of pages in various positions 
I follow [basic module creation](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_simple_module/Developing_a_Basic_Module)

In default.php I would like to make a ajax call to helper to refresh data, something like that :

```
$.ajax({ url: '/index.php?option=mod_doodlike&format=raw&tmpl=component,
```

all other parameters are in post

Is it possible ? what is the exact URL ? 
what should I put in helper.php (public function , class myclass extends JController) or in mod_module.php : `jimport('joomla.application.component.controller');`

or definitely it's a component I need to create ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so after some ggsearch, I succeeded thanks to [this post](http://www.simplifyyourweb.com/index.php/developers-corner/24-hands-on/39-including-jquery-into-a-joomla-module)

you have to call itself, best way to do is to use (in default.php):

```
 'url: "<?php echo JURI::getInstance() ?>",'
```

Then is mod_yourmodule.php intercept get or post "query" with JRequest::getVar because "$_POST['xxx']" does not work

```
 '$task = JRequest::getVar('task'); '
 'if($task == ....... '
 'and call the helper modyourmoduleHelper::youfuncion'
```

In helper, as you don't need all layouts I sent an echo of funcion returned value between “<”reply“>” tags and stoped joomla with jexit()

The reply will be the default.php + the echo easily parsed with :

```
 'var re = /<reply>(.*)<\/reply>/;'
 'var result = re.exec(T_output);       '       
 'if(result[1] != ''){ Displayfunction($.parseJSON(result[1]));}'
```

... finished

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't call a module URL as modules don't use them.

Your best bet would be to download and install the brand new **com_ajax** component that acts as an entry point for Ajax functionality. It's available for Joomla 1.5, 2,5 and 3.x, so whichever version you need, don't forget to select that branch first:

https://github.com/betweenbrain-llc/Joomla-Ajax-Interface

Hope this helps