# how can i call ajax to helper in joomla plugin not a module

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I want to call ajax to helper file in joomla plugin.My folder structure is myplugin.php,myplugin.xml,helper.php,tmpl->default.php. I am calling ajax from default.php but it returns html. This is my code.

```
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&format=raw&plugin=myplugin",
                    data: {"Type": "insert"},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (response)
                    {
```

Please help where i mistake.

Comment: Please check [Joomla how to make an ajax call to an helper.php module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332883/joomla-how-to-make-an-ajax-call-to-an-helper-php-module)

Comment: But i use plugin not a module.When i use this code for module it's work properly.